# Split chunks in webpack 4

Tags: webpack, chunks, webpack-4, code-splitting

I'm trying to migrate project from webpack 3 to webpack 4. In previous version there was configuration like:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: ['common', 'initApp'], filename: '[name].[hash].js' }),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: ['app'], children: true, minChunks: 2, filename: '[name].[hash].js' }),
```

How to migrate it correctly to webpack 4?

I tried next config:

```
optimization: {
  minimize: !development,
  noEmitOnErrors: true, //! Webpack 4
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      utils: {
        name: 'utils',
        test: /utils/,
        chunks: 'initial',
        reuseExistingChunk: true
      },
      initApp: {
        name: 'initApp',
        test: /initApp/,
      },
      common: {
        name: 'common',
        test: /common/,
        chunks: 'all',
      },
      app: {
        minChunks: 2,
        name: 'app',
        test: /app/,
      },
    },
  },

  minimizer: [],
  namedModules: development,
},
```

And here the issue that I have: some `my_module` (from node_modules) has next code (I moved it to entry point `utils`):

```
  let localeStrings;
  export function l10n(key, ...args) {
    if (!localeStrings) {
      throw new Error('l10nLib.l10n called before locale strings loaded');
    }
    /// Do some logic
  }
  // And here some function is initialize localeStrings that we are calling `initApp` entry point
```

Now with current config this chunk (from my_module) calling twice: first time from `initApp` and second time from `app` entry point and `localeStrings` variable first time initialized properly when it was called from `initApp` and the second time when it was called from `app` entry point `localeStrings` is `undefined`, why?